How to instruct WhatsApp API to open external links in webview instead of mobile browser
How to instruct WhatsApp API to open external links in whatsapp webview instead of mobile browser
We are using WhatsApp API from (Karix Provider) we need to open external links in webview instead of mobile browser similar to the app of dmrc
Reference https://www.delhimetrorail.com/

